# Cannot use DataTables Row Grouping Extension on Angular 2

Tags: angular, visual-studio, datatables

I'm writing an example about how to implement Row Grouping in an Angular 2 Project, being run thru VS2015. I thought just by installing the DT RowGrouping Extension via NPM and importing it in my component would work, but is seems not.

This is the result I get when running my app (checked thru the Chrome Console):
GET http://localhost:7800/datatables.net-rowgroup 404 (Not Found)

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:1234/datatables.net-rowgroup
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:1234/datatables.net-rowgroup
```

Below are the commands I input in the NPM in order to get installed the RowGroup Extension in our project:

```
>> npm install --save datatables.net-rowgroup
>> npm install --save datatables.net-rowgroup-dt
```

Something that has caught my attention, is what I'm getting in the Chrome Developer Tools in the ***Network*** Tab about all the downloaded files:

The information below is regarding the ***Headers*** Tab, inside ***Network*** Tab.

DataTables Styles:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1234/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:1234
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

DataTables Buttons:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1234/node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:1234
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

DataTables RowGroup Extension (There are differences here!!):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1234/datatables.net-rowgroup
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:1234
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

For some reason, the DT RowGroup's files are not being read from the ***node_modules*** folder, in spite of being the files there already...

I do thank you all in advance for your suggestions about what might be going on here...

Regards!!

This is the code snippet, FYI:

### data-table.component.ts

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-buttons';
import 'datatables.net-buttons.html5';
import 'datatables.net-rowgroup'; // --->>> Here is failing!!
import 'datetime-moment';
import 'dataTables.bootstrap.min';

@Component({
  selector: 'data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css', './data-table.component.css', './css/buttons.dataTables.min.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('tableElement') tableElement: ElementRef;

  currentDatatable: any = null;

  constructor() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MMM DD YYYY');
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  setConfig(config: any) {
    if (this.currentDatatable) {
      this.currentDatatable.destroy();
    }
    config.buttons = config.buttons || [{
        text: 'Download to Excel',
        extend: 'csv',
        className: 'button-to-link'
      }],
      config.oLanguage = {
        "sSearch": '<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
        "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_"
      };
    config.dom = '<"top"lf>t<"bottom"pi>B';
    this.currentDatatable = $(this.tableElement.nativeElement).DataTable(config);
  }

  getDataFromRow(row: any): Object {
    if ($(this.tableElement.nativeElement).find('td').length == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    var table = $(this.tableElement.nativeElement).DataTable();
    let result = table.row(row).data();
    return result;
  }
```

Below is my package.json file:

### package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular2-draggable": "^1.0.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup": "^1.0.2",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup-dt": "^1.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.0",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.0.9",
    "ngx-rating": "0.0.9",
    "npm": "^5.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.45",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Hello, I think you missed to add row-group on package.json , "datatables.net-rowgroup": "1.0.2", https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net-rowgroup , I also would suggest to use https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowexpansion instead

Comment: Hello Americo, Thanks for your reply firstly. I tried installing the "datatables.net-rowgroup" already, but I'm getting the same error; even after having tried restoring all this project's packages.  Regarding PrimeNG, I'll discuss the topic with my Team Members what do they think about, since this Project has been developed since its incepton with DataTables.net.  Once again thanks a lot!!